# Remove some parts of the String C#

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have a string like this

> <tr><td>14.54.49</td><td>SKUTTELG</td><td>001772377777</td><td>test </td><td>SKUTTELG - mottatt.  Vilt: Okse 2,5 år +  Jak</td></tr>

I wanted to get

> SKUUTELG 001772377777 test  SKUTTELG - mottatt.  Vilt: Okse 2,5 år +  Jak

Need to remove

> <tr><td>

I'm try it out like this...

```
var testString = "MY STRING"
var stringArray = testString.Split('<tr><td>');
stringArray.Remove("<tr><td>);
var output = String.Join("<tr><td>", stringArray);
```

But this is not working..

Comment: `'<tr><td>'` is not valid c#, you need to use `"<tr><td>"`

Comment: Do you also want to remove the `14.54.49`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right and you just need to strip the HTML tags in this case, a simple string replace on top of a split should do:

```
var testString = "your string";

var array = str.Split(new string[] { "<tr>", "<td>" }, 
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

return string.Join("", array.Skip(1)).Replace("</tr>", "").Replace("</td>", " ");
```

Basic steps:

- to split the array, use an array of strings  that includes both the `<tr>` and the `<td>` tag.
- then use LINQ to skip the first element and join the elements back together.
- replace the closing tags either with the empty string or with a space, depending on the spacing you want to end up with.

Comment: That will not insert spaces as shown in the OP's "wanted to get".

Comment: @DourHighArch Good point. Amended the code to replace tags with spaces and then trim the leading and trailing spaces at the end.

Comment: That will insert multiple spaces; perhaps only replace "</td>" with a space.

Comment: @DourHighArch I'm also not skipping the very first cell... sec.

Comment: @AnnaLear imagine if i have 2 lines like this.i read values using While loop row by row.. then How can i remove this date 14.54.49 ?  in two lines there's a different dates

Answer (score 1):

How about parsing an html with an [html parser](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

```
string html = @"<tr><td>14.54.49</td><td>SKUTTELG</td><td>001772377777</td><td>test </td><td>SKUTTELG - mottatt. Vilt: Okse 2,5 år + Jak</td></tr>";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var tds = String.Join(" ", doc.DocumentNode
                              .SelectNodes("//td").Select(x => x.InnerText)
                              .Skip(1));
```

If there are more than one `tr` in your table

```
var lines = String.Join("\n",doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")
                                .Select(node=>String.Join(" ",
                                                    node.Descendants("td").Skip(1)
                                                        .Select(x=>x.InnerText))));
```